# Is my implementation of a Rational number using classes acceptable?

Tags: java, rational-numbers

I am trying to finish my rational class for java and everywhere I have looked to make it finished doesn't have it near the same. I know I could use others programs that where made but the ones I have seen don't have it for where you put the input in when you run the program. This is the code I have so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Lab09ast
{
    private static int num, den;   // numerator and denominator of the rational number

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        enterData();
        Rational r = new Rational(num,den);
        r.displayData();
    }

    public static void enterData()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("\nEnter the numerator ----> ");
        num = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("\nEnter the denominator --> ");
        den = input.nextInt();
    }
}



class Rational
{

    public void displayData()
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(getNum() + "/" + getDen() + " equals " + getDecimal());
        System.out.println();
    }

    private void getGCF(int n1,int n2)
    {
        int rem = 0;
        do
        {
            rem = n1 % n2;
            if (rem == 0)
                gcf = n2;
            else
            {
                n1 = n2;
                n2 = rem;
            }
        }
        while (rem != 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot to post your code...

Comment: I did it should be up now

Comment: Thanks. But what is your question?

Comment: You code seems incomplete.  You are calling methods like `getDen` and `getDecimal` which you aren't showing us.  Also, you're missing the constructor for your `Rational` class.

Comment: You are also calling a non-existant constructor.

Comment: please post your full code...

Comment: My question is where to add and how to add the methods for getNum()  getDen() and getDecimal(). I have tried for a while and I still couldn't solve it by myself.

Comment: I assume you would just add it within the class itself. What *specific* problem are you having? If you're asking questions about how to write methods and where to place them, that's pretty trivial and I'd recommend you look up a tutorial.

Comment: Flagged unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Member variables `num` and `den` (numerator and denominator) are in class `Lab09ast`. These should be in class `Rational`. Do you understand the concepts of [classes and objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html)?

It's logical that a `Rational` object, which you make from the class `Rational`, has member variables for the numerator and denominator.

Also, those member variables must not be `static`. See [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) to learn what `static` means and why it is not appropriate for these member variables.

The methods `getNum()` and `getDen()` should return the values of the `num` and `den` member variables, and should also be in class `Rational`.

Class `Rational` should also have a [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) that [takes two arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html), for the numerator and denominator. You're already calling that constructor in the `main` method of class `Lab09ast`, but it's not in your class `Rational` yet.